# How to let summary() function in r output categorical variable level names of a model instead of level numbers?

Tags: r

I use the mixed effect model.

Data is like：

```
  testScore bodyLength mountainRange site obs
1 16.147309   165.5485      Bavarian    a   1
2 33.886183   167.5593      Bavarian    a   2
3  6.038333   165.8830      Bavarian    a   3
4 18.838821   167.6855      Bavarian    a   4
5 33.862328   169.9597      Bavarian    a   5
6 47.043246   168.6887      Bavarian    a   6
```

Here is the formula: Formula: testScore ~ mountainRange + (bodyLength)+(1|obs)

And summary() output:

```
Fixed effects:
                Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)     47.83474   16.06676   2.977
mountainRange1 -27.00423    2.48719 -10.857
mountainRange2   9.57854    1.91480   5.002
mountainRange3 -10.79500    1.96837  -5.484
mountainRange4  18.11046    2.32788   7.780
```

I want to let summary() function in r output categorical variable level names(Bavarian/Ligurian/...) of a model instead of level numbers(mountainRange1/mountainRange2...).
I remember it can be done, but now it doesn't work. How can i make it?

Comment: `factor(x, levels=c("sesHigh", "sesMid", "sesLow"))`?

Comment: Sadly it doesn't work for me...

Comment: I restart the R session several times, and it works... I don't know how but it do works:(